# How to change the value of a nested object's property with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, use-state, react-functional-component

Here's my nested object.

```js
const [mileStones, setMileStones] = useState({
    milestone1: [
      {
        checked: true,
        name: 'Preapre the fitting',
        prepareFittingMileStones: [
          { mileStone: 'Solid wood for frame/support', checked: true },
          { mileStone: 'Plywood for frame/support', checked: false },
          { mileStone: 'Plywood for panels', checked: true },
          { mileStone: 'Plywood for partition', checked: true },
          { mileStone: 'Fixing supports', checked: true },
          { mileStone: 'Fixing panels', checked: false },
          { mileStone: 'Check with level scale and plumb', checked: true },
          { mileStone: 'Cutting the Veneer as per size', checked: false },
          { mileStone: 'Fixing of veneer on the panels', checked: false },
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Rendering multiple checkbox, in a flatlist. I want something like this, but it isn't working!

```js
<CheckBox value={item.checked} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
  onPress={() => {
    mileStones.milestone1.prepareFittingMileStones.checked = !mileStones.milestone1.prepareFittingMileStones.checked
    setMileStones({ mileStones })
  }}
/>
```

I want to toggle the value of the checkbox when pressed and save the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new object with mileStone1 properties. Then set the state with new milestone object.

```
<CheckBox value={item.checked} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
  onPress={() => {
      let newMileStone = { ...mileStones }
      newMileStone.milestone1.prepareFittingMileStones.checked = 
             !mileStones.milestone1.prepareFittingMileStones.checked
      setMileStones({ newMileStone });
  }}
/>
```